# How to determine the best fitted model by AIC between lm(y~x),lm(log(y)~x), drc(y~x) in R

Tags: r, aic, logarithm, model-comparison

```
library(aomisc)
library(drc)

m.linear <- lm(y ~ x, data = data)
m.exponential <- lm(log(y) ~ x, data = data)
m.asymptotic <- drm(y ~ x, data = data, fct = DRC.asymReg())
m.logistic <- drm(y ~ x, data = data, fct = L.3())
m.gompertz <- drm(y ~ x, data = data, fct = G.3())
```

I want to use AIC value to determine the best fitted model, however, the AIC(m.exponential) seems not correct.

Comment: With one response and one predictor, why lean on AIC? Some combination of plotting data and fitted response and scientific knowledge should get you where you want to be.

Comment: The problem now is that the fit of a rising curve results in a logistic model. It seems to be the first half of the fit and the logistic model, so it's impossible to tell if it's accurate or not.

Comment: I have seen that problem quite often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't compare AIC between a model fitted to the original data and another model fitted to logarithmized data.

In addition, Be *extremely* careful about comparing AICs between models fitted using different tools, like `lm()` versus `drm()`. Different implementations have different definitions of "the" AIC.

I recommend you compare predictive accuracy on holdout data, or on out-of-bag data in a bootstrap. (Remember [the bias correction](https://otexts.com/fpp3/ftransformations.html) if you are estimating conditional means using logged data.)

Comment: What usually differs is the definition of the log-likelihood of which AIC is a function.